# iChat Style Interface

Tags: c#, ichat

I'm trying to create an iChat-style insterface (ie: message bubbles) in C# for a project. Can anyone suggest or offer ideas on how best to achieve this? My first thoughts were with WPF but I've never ventured in that direction before; I've been sticking with WinForms so far and, if possible, would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also just use good old photoshop.

make a balloon which is made out of 9 blocks.

the upper left corner, the top bit, the top right bit, the left bit, the middle bit, the right bit, the bottom left bit, the bottom bit and the bottom right bit.

by making sure the middle bits can be repeated (without seeing a pattern) you can make the balloons as big as you want and this way scale it to the text

so with these building blocks:

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

you can make:

```
 1 2 2 2 2 2 3
 4 5 5 5 5 5 6
 4 5 5 5 5 5 6
 7 8 8 8 8 8 9
```