# How can we create a roundrect button using win32 API in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I am creating skinned application in which I want a skinned roundrect button, can someone help me out in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

an answer to another question I gave some time back might be relevant for you as well:

[iChat Style Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306574/ichat-style-interface/1306655#1306655)

You'll have to 'subclass' the button and do your own painting course.